# how to insert fontawesome icon in ajax.actionlink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to add icon tag to the ajax.actionlink?

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Subscribe", "Subscribe", "UserManagement", new { id = ViewBag.UserId }, 
    new AjaxOptions 
    { 
        UpdateTargetId = "video-userinfo-subscribe", 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }, new { id = "video-userinfo-subscribe" })
```

Comment: You create an extension for `AjaxHelper` that will include the `<i class="..."></i>` inside your anchor. But it might be easier to write this out yourself in plain html tags unless you have lots of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, you can't, or at least, it's inadvisable. As you detailed in your comment on @Shyju's answer, applying a class to the `a` tag will have unintended side effects. Font Awesome is designed to be applied to an empty inline element, i.e.:

```
<i class="fa fa-foo"></i>
```

The longer answer is to simply not use `Html.ActionLink` or `Ajax.ActionLink`. It's just a shortcut for when you need a *simple* link, simple being the keyword. As soon as you want to do something like add an icon, you're out of that territory. Instead do something like:

```
<a id="video-userinfo-subscribe" href="@Url.Action("Subscribe", "UserManagement", new { id = ViewBag.UserId })">
    <i class="fa fa-foo"></i>
    Subscribe
</a>
```

But, what about your AJAX? Well, here again is one more reason in a long line of reasons to not use the `Ajax.*` family of helpers. They're stupidly inflexible and brittle. You're always going to be much better off applying your own JavaScript than relying on the Web Form-era holdovers.

```
$('#video-userinfo-subscribe').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post(url, function (html) {
        $('#video-userinfo-subscribe').replaceWith(html);
    });
});
```

Be careful with this kind of thing, though. You're replacing the same element you're binding to, so you should either:

1. Bind to a delegate (i.e. a parent of the `a` tag):

   ```
   $('#parentElement').on('click', '#video-userinfo-subscribe', function (e) {
   ```
2. replace some other element or simply the content of the `a` tag:

   ```
   $('#video-userinfo-subscribe').html(html);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its possible with a trick. Try like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("YourText", "YourAction", "YourController", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "YourDivTargetToUpdate" }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @id="myActionLinkId" })
    <script>$("#myActionLinkId").prepend("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> ");</script>
```

Just, replace for your own variables.

Answer (score 1):

I know this must be old but this might help other

```
 <div class="col-2 text-center">
        <a data-ajax="true"
    data-ajax-loading="#loading"
    data-ajax-mode="replace"
    data-ajax-update="#editBid"
    href="/Bids/_EditBid/?bidId=@Model.BidId"
    class="btn btn-sample"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a>
```

Comment: just forget about the first line with the div

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by [Erik VzGz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277336/how-to-insert-fontawesome-icon-in-ajax-actionlink/49904961#49904961). It is simple and easy to implement. However, I had to change it to be based on class rather than id because I wanted to use it in a table where each row had the links.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("YourText", "YourAction", "YourController", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "YourDivTargetToUpdate" }, new { @class = "btn btn-success myActionLink" })

<script>
  $('.myActionLink').prepend("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> ");
</script>
```

Also, if you don't want any text on the button, change "YourText" to " ". You have to have at least one character or it will give an error.